# Connecting Java and Teradata: The UserId, Password or Account is invalid

Tags: java, teradata

I have been trying to connect to Teradata

```
Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
        String connectionString = "jdbc:teradata://xxx.xxxxxx.com/database=xxxxxx,  tmode=ANSI,  charset=UTF8";
        String user = "Rocket512";
        String password = "aui8mn5";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, user, password);
```

Got the following

```
  Exception in thread "main" com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata Database] 
[TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 8017] [SQLState 28000] The UserId, Password or Account is invalid.
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:300)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericLogonController.run(GenericLogonController.java:666)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.<init>(TDSession.java:216)
```

**I know that the host is specified correctly since i did not get `UnknownHost Exception.`
Also I have double checked my userid and password are correct.**

---

I ran query suggested by @beni23 (thank you)

```
select * 
from dbc.logonoff 
where logdate >= date '2013-10-31'
```

Here is the result that I got

[image]

What is `Bad Password`? I used SQL Assistant with this very password and it works great. Why cannot i connect with Java?

Comment: ARe you sure usernames are case insensitive?

Comment: Yes they are. Also, I have tried both ways

Comment: This should work (case-insensitive UID/PWD): java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:teradata://<servername>/database=<databasename>","<username>","<password>");

Comment: @BoratSagddiev did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following might not give you a solution, but might point you in the right direction.  I think you'll want to check the `dbc.logonoff` table in teradata through a console to make sure that your user is not locked or get an idea whether your driver is hitting teradata.

```
select * 
  from dbc.logonoff 
 where logdate >= date '2013-10-31'
```

Comment: Your output is showing the user as ROCKET512, are you sure you're setting username and password correctly? Try swapping them.

Comment: I am sorry this is a typo. Everything is correct. `username = "Rocket512"`, `password = "aui8mn5"`. I mean i did not mess up with username and password

Answer (score 7):

LDAP Authentication failures will not be captured in `DBC.LogOnOff` as a `Bad Password` event because the authentication doesn't take place on the database.

Typically the error message you are receiving, `The UserId, Password or Account is invalid.`, is indicative of the user account being locked on the database.

```
SELECT U.UserName
     , U.ProfileName
     , U.DefaultAccount
     , COALESCE(P.MAXLOGONATTEMPTS, S.MAXLOGONATTEMPTS) AS MaxLogonAttempts_
     , U.LockedCount
     , U.LockedDate
  FROM dbc.UsersV U
  LEFT JOIN
       dbc.ProfileInfoV P
    ON P.ProfileName = U.ProfileName   
  CROSS JOIN
       dbc.SecurityDefaults S
 WHERE UserName = 'Rocket512';
```

If `LockedCount` is not `0` than a failed logon attempt has occurred since the last successful logon to the database.

If `LockedDate` is not `NULL` it represents the date which the account was last locked.

`MaxLogonAttempts_` will tell you how many times you can attempt to logon using database authentication (TD2) before the account is locked.

A couple of things I would suggest:

1. Remove whitespace between the parameters of `connectString`
2. Put the User and Password parameters in the `connectString`
3. Using original code above modify the `connectString` to add: `,ACCOUNT=$AMRWRW&DrT&r` which should match what is returned by the query in my response above (I have added `DefaultAccount`).

**EDIT: 11/12/13**
May I suggest you download Teradata Studio Express and attempt to make a connection to the same Teradata system using JDBC much like you are here in your code. This may help shed light on the parameters you need to specify in your connection string in order to make the connection successful. You should be able to setup your connection parameters in Teradata Studio Express the same as you have here in your code and see if it works.

Using LDAP as the logon mechanism for a user that has not been granted the explicit right to logon with a NULL password has resulted in the error message `The UserId, Password or Account is invalid.'. I received this the other day using a privileged account without changing my logon mechanism from LDAP to TD2.

What does the following SQL return?

```
SELECT *
  FROM DBC.LogonRulesV
 WHERE UserName = 'Rocket512';
```

It may not return anything, which is okay. This simply means you ability to logon with that userid from any host on the system has not been explicitly granted or revoked.

**EDIT: 05/22/18**
The “Bad Password” event for an externally authenticated user may will appear in the event log when the provided password and the what is stored on the directory server do not match. In certain scenarios you can verify this by using `ldapsearch` from the PDN to submit an inquiry directly to the LDAP directory. You can find more details about using this command in the Security Administration manual. I’ve discovered this trying to triage a problem with a subset of user accounts that fail to authenticate to the directory. I felt it would be appropriate to update this answer with more details as my lead in statement at the top is not 100% accurate.

Comment: + 1 THank You. I have verified that I am not locked. I can access easily via sql assistant. Also, I have tried to remove spaces and put everythig in the connection string, but go the same error

Comment: @BoratSagddiev - I have added a third suggestion on the off chance the lack of the account being specified was causing a problem.

Comment: Thank You, I have tried all this, including modifying the string. `MaxLogonAttempts = 15`. `Locked Count = 3`. Still the same error

Comment: @BoratSagddiev - I have added additional details above to help triage the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Reading this article [Troubleshooting Security: The UserId, Password or Account is invalid.](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_5.html#2403_2403apB1113) we can see the typical reason of this error.

> **Cause:** LOGMECH=LDAP is specified, and the username/password credentials
> are redundantly provided in the both LOGDATA and as separate
> connection parameters.
>
> **Solution:** Identify LDAP users via LOGDATA, or
> via separate username/password parameters, but not both
> simultaneously.

So, you should check this case. May be you can get connection without user/password

Comment: +1 Thank you. I tried this and this is what i have: `[Error 1032] [SQLState HY000] Single Sign-On NOT supported for Mechanism TD2.`

Comment: @BoratSagddiev I have seen this problem before. Please, read this topic http://forums.teradata.com/forum/connectivity/error-8017-the-userid-password-or-account-is-invalid

Comment: @Ilya link is out of date

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might have more luck with:

```
String driver = "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver";
String conUrl="jdbc:teradata://xxx.xxxxxx.com/database=xxxxxx,USER=Rocket512,PASSWORD=aui8mn5,tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8";
Class.forName(driver);
Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl);
```

If that doesn't work make sure to use the latest jdbc driver.

Comment: +1 It is the latest on from http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver still the same Error 8017

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error and followed all the suggestions given in here. My account was not locked and I was able to connect to the DB with the same username and password, via SQL assistance editor.

The solution worked for me was adding following line in the connection string: LOGMECH=LDAP.

You need to know the logon mechanism for your Teradata, or you can reach out to your DBA team, as I did.  So your connection string will look something like this:

String connurl="jdbc:teradata://xx/database=xx,USER=xx,PASSWORD=xx,tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8,LOGMECH=LDAP";

Comment: THANKS! Looking for this LOGMECH=LDAP parameter everywhere!

Comment: how do you specify the domain name? password?